# OMNET++: .gdbinit: no such file or directory?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am using Inet, and I did some modifications for my work. I created a new class of addresses (I do not have any error). When I want to use this class in my files .cc
I get this error:

> `<!> Warning: opp_run: Cannot check library ../../src/inet: ../../src//libinet.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK12MYAddress3strEv`
>
> `<!> Error during startup: Cannot load library '../../src//libinet.so': ../../src//libinet.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK12MYGAddress3strEv.
>   OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2011 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
>   Version: 4.2.2, build: 120327-7947143, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE`
>
> See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
>
> `End.`
>
> `Simulation terminated with exit code: 1` (I don't know what it means)

I used the debbug and I get:

> `.gdbinit: no such file or directory`
>   But I don't know what it means as well.

So, I would appreciate it if you could help me. I have no idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore the missing .gdbinit warning. It has nothing to do with your problem.

The base cause is most likely that the new Address class is not included in the created shared library. Be sure to recreate your makefile and check if you are using .cc as an extension and that the file is under the src directory.